# jdbctemplate not able to retrieve data

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I have method execute() which calls saveCom() which is requires_new method and commits data and same is then retrieved below by calling saveCom somehow I am not able retrieve the data

```
 @Async
    @Transactional   
     public void execute(){

       commService.saveCom(comm);//this is a Requires_New method.Data gets ccommmited here
       List<Comm> commList = commDao.getComm(comm);
    }

//get is used then to retrieve the data
  public List<Comm> getCom(Comm comm) throws PimsAppException {
        List<Comm> restriction_list = new ArrayList<Comm>();
        try {   

                    Object[] updateObjs = new Object[]{comm.getCommId(),comm.getCountryofDestination(),
                            comm.getPortOfEntry()};
                    restriction_list = jdbcTemplate.query(""    SELECT *        FROM   pims.pdcommrestriction   WHERE  ( commodityid = ?  AND countryofdestination = ?   AND portofentry = ? ),updateObjs,new CommMapper());


        }

        catch (Throwable e) {
            Logger.getLogger().error("Class=CommImpl; Method=getComm "+e);

        }
    return restriction_list;
    }
```

After saveCom method is executed,i can see that data has been inserted into the DB but when I try to retrieve the data in the next line by calling getComm().It is not able to retrieve the data.....

Is there any issue with jdbctemplate not able to retrieve the data after data has been commited above using Requires_NEW?

**UPDATE**:
If I remove the @Transactional on execute,getCom is able to retrieve the data

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Rips do one test and run the sql with the same parameters in your database using a mysql cli to make sure that it returns some data.

Comment: Try this `@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)` on your execute() method.